# why get is always hitting the first route

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express.

I have 2 routes:

```
router.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {

router.get('/search', function (req, res, next) {
```

Every time I call GET `http://localhost:3000/users/search?name=@` I hit the fist route instead of the second one?

What should I change?

Comment: You can change their order, so the app will only check `/:id` when `/search` didn't match. Or, Express uses `path-to-regexp`, which supports [providing a format with a parameter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp#custom-match-parameters) – e.g. `/:id(\d+)` (only numeric `id`s match).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `/:id` matches anything include `/search`.  It thinks the id is 'search'.
Try putting the '/search' route first, or change it to `/find/:id`.